# Access VBA - Dialog Box. Looking for an specific file

Tags: vba, ms-access

Now I have this code in order to open a dialog box to search for a concrete type of file, a .txt called memory: `memory.txt`

So:

```
    Dim S As String
S = OpenCommDlg("C:\memory.txt")

If IsNull(S) Or S = "" Then Exit Sub
```

Unfortunately, this opens a dialog box in `C:\`, of course, but looking for image type archives, which is absolutely not what I'm looking for. You can see this at the right side of the attached image:

[image: Dialog box looks for images]

Anyone knows how to modify this code in order to find the kind of archive we are looking for, and it's name...

Comment: The file type list will be in your function `OpenCommDlg()`. Use Shift+F2 to go to its definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `FileDialog` method. This will save the full file path to your `s` string, and you can add multiple filters to filter by file type.

```
Dim s As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    If .Show Then s = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Debug.Print s
```

If you want to automatically fill in the inputbox with your filename, then you can just add this line to the with statement:

```
.InitialFileName = "C:\memory.txt"
```